# Sides of similar triangles

Tags: triangles

[image]

In the attached question, I am able to find x but not y. I know that sides of similar triangles are proportionate but that's not helping here. And I guess the third side of the smaller tringle would be (y+3)/2 but how to calculate y?

X would 68 degrees as it is opposite to the propotionate side y+3. (corresponding angles of similar triangles are equal).

Comment: What did you get for $x$ (and how did you get it)?

Comment: Have added in the post

Comment: Wouldn't the angle at B be the same as the angle at P and thus 68° ?

Comment: My bad. Didn't use proper logic. But still not able to see why P equals B and not A.

Answer (score 1):

Note that B = P = 68 and $x$ = 180 - 54 - 68 = 58. The similar triangles leads to the ratio

$$\frac{y+3}{2y}=\frac y {y+2}$$

Edit: There may some issue with the problem. Either B is 68 or 58 would mean y > y + 2, which is not true.

Comment: Sorry, why P equals B and not A?

Comment: @Ramit - A=P is impossible, which would mean B=58>54 and y>y+2.

Comment: If B is 68, and 68>54 i.e. y>y+2? (just trying to understand)

Comment: @Ramit - you're right. both are unlikely. Some is off with the problem.